# DataTables AJAX search uses ambiguous columns

Tags: jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

The output for a particular DataTable had to use a `LEFT JOIN` on several tables to get the data needed. When I type anything into the search box for the DataTable, I'm given the error `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous` when it tries to ask the remote server for search results.

Server side query that loads the initial table AJAX request:

```
select
    orders.*,
    orders.id as id,
    order_items.*
left join order_items
    orders.id on order_items.order_id
where
    orders.store_id = 1
group by
    orders.id
```

When DataTables 1.10 adds it's automatic search filter to the original query, it sends it to the PHP server side handler package `yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle:3.0` which then tacks it onto the `WHERE` portion of the query and returns the new filtered results.

How do I force DataTables (either on the jQuery side or the PHP server side) to prepend the relevant table name to the search fields before sending the request over AJAX?

Comment: Surely it's up to you to decide how the parameter is used in the query?  Please show the server-side query code.

Comment: @markpsmith that's exactly what I'm trying to figure out how to control. At the moment, DataTables makes that decision on it's own. Please see updated post.

Comment: I wonder if it's because you're returning orders.id twice - once in `orders.*` and again `orders.id as id`.  Try removing the line `orders.id as id`

Comment: @markpsmith if I remove `orders.id as id` then `orders.id` gets overwritten by `order_items.id` in the query result set which is undesirable.

Comment: ah right - so you actually got 3 fields called `id`. Can you change the query to return only the columns you want, instead of using `*`?

Comment: I should only have ONE field called `id` in the final result set. The explicit field overwrites any of the others so I don't have to drop every other field from the table into an array just because of one field not wanted. The DataTable uses all fields and more (except `order_items.id`) because appended mutator fields need to do calculations based off them.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and found the answer by chance, while I know this is an old question I thought I'd post my answer here.

In my instance I had two SQL tables (Offices and Regions) both of which had an id field.  When using the pagination I would receive the same error as you.

To fix this I needed to set the name attribute on the columns in the JavaScript.  This allowed the pagination to work correctly without any issues.

```
     dtbl = $('#tblReport').DataTable( {
          columns: [
               { data: 'id', name: 'offices.id', visible: false },
               { data: 'name' }
          ], 
          "serverSide": true
     });
```